# Powershell / cmd command to change an AD users password

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, active-directory

I have tried to find an answer to this but maybe it is just not possible.

So I have several AD Users for different tasks.

- for-a.surname
- for-b.surname
- for-c.surname

And of course I have to change the passwords for these AD users on a regular basis.
For this I always log in with every one of these users and CTRL-ALT-DEL --> Change Password.

What I am looking for is a Powershell / Commandline command to change all these users passwords without having to acctually switch.

e.g.

1. I am logged in as for-a.surname
2. Open Powershell / CMD
3. `ChangePW for-b.surname`
4. Enter old password
5. Enter new password
6. Enter new password again
7. done

Comment: If you have access to Active Directory or remote management for active directory, you can right-click a user, and change password from there. If you really want to go the logged in route, from cmd: `net user <username> <password>` or `net user <username> *` the * one will then prompt you to enter a new password. Neither option require you to know the old password.

Comment: @LPChip: All of that assumes OP has domain admin rights, and given the post it doesn't sound like they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the PowerShell cmdlet [Set-ADAccountPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword)
Works exactly like what you described (you can omit the "-Identity" parameter name).
`Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity for-b.surname`

You can also pass the old and new passwords as parameters (more examples in the link above):

```
$old = Read-Host "Old password" -AsSecureString
$new = Read-Host "New password" -AsSecureString
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity for-b.surname -OldPassword $old -NewPassword $new
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity for-c.surname -OldPassword $old -NewPassword $new
```

Note that passing `-NewPassword` without also providing `-OldPassword` will **reset** the password, not change it. The cmdlet will only interactively query for the old password if the new one isn't passed.

`net user <username> newpassword` requires administrative permissions and will **reset** the password, not change it.

The cmdlet is part of the ActiveDirectory module.
To install the module on Windows 10/11 (internet connection required):
`Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools*`

To install the module on Windows Server:
`Install-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-ADDS-Tools`

Answer (score 4):

The Ctrl-Alt-Del screen is titled "Change **a** password" – the "User name" field is editable and it lets you enter any user name recognized by the system, not necessarily your own. (I just tried it on a standalone PC against a MIT Kerberos principal.)

Self-service password change in AD is primarily done through the Kerberos "kpasswd" protocol. There's no built-in CLI tool in Windows for that, as far as I know, but you can install either the MIT Kerberos or Heimdal Kerberos tools and use the `kpasswd` command. (In most cases it does not require a full domain join.)

If you have access to Linux (including WSL), `krb5-user` on Debian or Ubuntu would do the job, though the [MIT Kerberos for Windows](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/) tools include it as well. (I would also expect [Kerberos.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Kerberos.NET) to have it as part of `bruce`; though apparently it doesn't, yet.)

```
$ kpasswd for-a.surname@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: I never noticed that the user field in "Change a password" is editable. This already makes it a lot easier.

Comment: On windows, you can use `net user <username> newpassword`